# Data loaded with useEffect hook but don't display

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am loading data from firebase in `useEffect` and I am trying to display it.

Data are loaded but don't display. I don't understand why.

UserDetails.js:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import base from '../base';

import { ref, onValue } from "firebase/database";

const UserDetails = () => {

  const { userId } = useParams();
  const [user, setUser] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const usersRef = ref(base, '/users');

    onValue(usersRef, (snapshot) => {
      const users = snapshot.val();
      let user = {};
      if (users !== null) {
        user = users.filter(user => user.id == userId)[0]
        setUser({ user });
      }
    });
  }, [userId]);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Hello {user.first_name}</p>
    </>
  )
}

export default UserDetails
```

Error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first_name')
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first_name')
> at UserDetails

Comment: Hi, are you sure that userId trigger the useEffect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user` is already an object you just pass it to the setter function of the state you don't need curly braces:

```js
setUser(user);
```

```js
<>
 <p>Hello {user?.first_name}</p>
</>
```

---

with

```js
setUser({ user });
```

you are setting an object with a property `user` that is an object containing the user info so you have to access the user name this way:

```js
<p>Hello {user?.user?.first_name}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The effect does not fire until *after* the first render of your component. So on the first render, in the return statement `user` has whatever initial value it was assigned in `useState`, which here is undefined. This causes an error, as we're trying to read a property of an undefined variable.